# error: expected expression before ']' token when passing an array as an arguement in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, arguments, parameter-passing

I am new to C. Was writing this so it takes the strings from the passed array and makes it a single sentence. But I got this error, I am not good with arrays in C. I can use some help from you guys. I did search an answer for this and couldn't find.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char smash(char arr[20][20]) {
    char tmp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])];
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
        strcat(tmp, arr[i]);
        strcat(tmp, " ");

    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    char list[][6] = {"hello", "world"};
    printf("%s", smash(list[]));
}
```

Error

```
error: expected expression before ']' token
printf("%s", smash(list[]));
                        ^
```

Comment: `printf("%s", smash(list[]));` ==> `printf("%s", smash(list));` but this won't be enough to make your program work.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is also wrong. You will get the size of the pointer not the array itself. You could pass an extra parameter for `size`.

Comment: And the array being passed is not compatible with the parameter declaration.  The *first* dimension does not matter, as the argument is converted to a pointer and the parameter is interpreted as a pointer, but **the second and all subsequent dimensions need to match exactly**.  This is a matter of the type that the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of errors in this small piece of code.

First, to address the compiler error: `list[]` is not a valid expression.  If you want to pass `list` to the function, leave the braces out:

```
printf("%s", smash(list));
```

This will then bring up another error.  The function is expecting a `char [20][20]` as it's argument, but that's not what you're passing in.  Since arrays as parameters are converted to a pointer, the argument type is actually `char (*)[20]` i.e. a pointer to an array of `char` of size 20.  Note also that this conversion only occurs for the outermost array dimension, not all.

Since you're passing in a `char [2][6]` which gets converted to a `char (*)[6]` this is a type mismatch.  So change the parameter to `char arr[][6]`.

Then you're attempting to get the size of the array parameter inside of the function:

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```

Since arrays cannot be directly passed to a function due to the conversion mentioned earlier, `arr` is actually a pointer and not an array, so you won't get the result you expect from this.  You'll need to pass the number of array elements as a separate parameter.

Then you're calling `strcat` on `tmp`.  This function will only work if the destination already has a null terminated string in it.  Since `tmp` was not initialized or written to prior to the first call to `strcat`, you end up reading uninitialized bytes and potentially past the end of the array which will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This can be fixed by setting the first byte of the array to 0 before the loop to make it an empty string:

```
tmp[0] = 0;
for ...
```

Then there's the problem with the return type.  The function is declared to return a `char` but you're giving a `char *` to the return statement, and at the point the function is called it is passed to `printf` where the `%s` format specifier is expecting a `char *` parameter.

So change the return type of the function from `char` to `char *`.

Finally, you're returning a pointer to a local variable in the function.  This variable's lifetime ends when the function returns, so the returned pointer is invalid and using it will also trigger undefined behavior.

You'll need change `tmp` to a pointer and dynamically allocate memory for it using `malloc`.  This also means you'll need to save the return value of the function in a separate variable which you can then pass to `printf` to print and then pass to `free` to free the memory.

After making all this changes, the resulting code should look like this:

```
char *smash(char arr[][6], int len) {
    // enough for len strings plus len spaces
    char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(arr[0]) * len + len + 1); 
    tmp[0] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        strcat(tmp, arr[i]);
        strcat(tmp, " ");

    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    char list[][6] = {"hello", "world"};
    char *result = smash(list, sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]));
    printf("%s", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```